# Generating random path in 2d array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a path in 2d array it supposes to go from point A to B currently I only try to make a path currently I have this script below some time it works sometimes it gets stuck in an endless loop.

My final goal is to make three random paths going from point A to B, C, D...

I hope you guys can help me.

I don't want to use a star since I want it to be random and not the shortest path.

```js
var startRow = 0;
var startCol = 0;
var curRowPos = 0;
var curColPos = 0;
var width = 10;
var height = 10;
var mapCode = 0; 
var finalCode = 0;
var dirction = [];
var map = GenerateArray(width,height,true);
var pos = {
    start : [],
    end : [],
}
GeneratePath();
printmap();
function printmap(){
    var res  = '';
    console.log('-----------------------------------')
    for(var i = 0; i < width; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < height; j++){
            res += map[i][j] +','
        }
        res += '\n'
    }
    console.log(res)
    console.log('-----------------------------------')
}
function GenerateArray(width,height,empty){
        var arr = new Array(2); 
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++){
            arr[x] = new Array(2); 
            for (var y = 0; y < height; y++){
                arr[x][y] = 0;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
function GeneratePath()
    {
        startRow = curRowPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);  
        curColPos = startCol;         // pick starting column, row is 0
        map[startRow][ startCol]  = 1; // assign 1 to start square
        pos.start = [startRow,startCol]
        
        while ( finalCode == 0 )  
        {      
            getDirections();
            SelectDir(); 
            printmap();         // random selection of available directions
        }

        return;
    }
function getDirections(){
        var N ,S,W,E;
        N = curRowPos - 1 > 0 && map[curRowPos - 1][ curColPos] == 0;
        S = curRowPos + 1 < width && map[curRowPos + 1][ curColPos] == 0;
        W = curColPos + 1 < height && map[curRowPos ][ curColPos+ 1] == 0;
        E = curColPos -1 >= 0  && curColPos < height && map[curRowPos ][ curColPos- 1] == 0 ;
        direction = [];
        if(N){
            direction.push("north");
        }
        if(S){
            direction.push("south");
        }
        if(W){
            direction.push("west");
        }
        if(E){
            direction.push("east");
        }
    }
function SelectDir(){
        var select = 0;
        var selection = "";
        if (direction.length != 0) // select random direction from list
        {
            select = Math.floor(Math.random() * direction.length);  
            selection = direction[select];
        }
        else selection = "blocked"; // no moves available
        if (curColPos == width-1)
        {
            finalCode = 1;    // set final square if row 7
        }
        if(finalCode == 1){
            pos.end = [startRow,startCol]
            return;
        }
        switch (selection)
        {
            case "blocked":
                map[curRowPos][ curColPos] = -1;
                //BackUp();       // back up to last avail square with move options
                break;
            case "north":
                curRowPos = curRowPos - 1;
                map[curRowPos][curColPos] = 1;
                direction = [];
                break;
            case "south":
                curRowPos = curRowPos + 1;
                map[curRowPos][curColPos]  = 1;
                direction = [];
                break;
            case "east":
                curColPos = curColPos - 1;
                map[curRowPos][curColPos]  = 1;
                direction = [];
                break;
            case "west":
                curColPos = curColPos + 1;
                map[curRowPos][curColPos] = 1;
                direction = [];
                break;
            default:
                break;          
        }
        return;
    }
function BackUp()
    {
        console.log("backup")
        map[curRowPos][curColPos] = 0; // set element to indicate no movement
        direction = [];
        var tempN = 0;
        var tempS = 0;
        var tempE = 0;
        var tempW = 0;
        
        // start logic to determine last space before dead end.
        // gets mapCode for surrounding square, assign to temp int.
        printmap();
 
        if (curRowPos < width)
        {
            tempN = map[curRowPos-1][ curColPos];
        }
 
        if (curRowPos > 0)
        {
            tempS = map[curRowPos + 1][ curColPos];
        }
 
        if (curColPos < width)
        {
            tempE = map[curRowPos][ curColPos-1];
        }
 
        if (curColPos > 0)
        {
            tempW = map[curRowPos][ curColPos+1];
        }
 
        // determine highest value of temp int's. Highest value is the
        // square previous to dead end. Set curRowPos or or curColPos accordingly.
       
        if (tempN > tempS)
        {
            if (tempN > tempE)
            {
                if (tempN > tempW)        
                {
                    curRowPos = curRowPos + 1;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    curColPos = curColPos - 1;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else if (tempE > tempW)
            {
                curColPos = curColPos + 1;
                return;    
            }
            else
            {
                curColPos = curColPos - 1;
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (tempS > tempE)
        {
            if (tempS > tempW)
            {
                curRowPos = curRowPos - 1;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                curColPos = curColPos - 1;
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (tempE > tempW)
        {
            curColPos = curColPos + 1;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            curColPos = curColPos - 1;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is the only backtrack() call commented out?

Comment: When i call it is going to the prev place and then to the same place again... so I commented it

Comment: I believe this can be solved by making backtrack block the direction backtracked from - as it obviously leads to a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would not use global variables for that, as that makes the code more difficult to understand when you want to read it later on. Replacing them with function arguments should work in this case.

It seems that hitting a dead end will make the algorithm reach an endless loop - as it won't do anything in that case.

There are two more problems - the first one is, how do you define a random path? From what distribution should it be? Should it be a random shortest path? (Generally, the shortest path isn't unique.) Should it be as long as possible? (That's the Traveling Salesman Problem, something I believe you want to avoid)

This brings me to the second problem - the backtracking will make it take exponential time if unlucky. Maybe you want the path to be short, but not always the shortest path. In that case, the A* algorithm can still be used! Feeding it random weights for the edges will make it take a path that is still the shortest according to some metric, but that metric will be different for different paths - and this is even parametrizable - adding less noise will make the resulting path shorter and closer to the shortest path, while adding more noise will make it the algorithm take longer (but still quadratic time because this is the worst case of A*)

Comment: i used the Global vars just for the demonstratuin after I will fix it to works as a funtions.
My friend solved it using random waypoints and connect them with a random path